# HTML(5) with meteor

Tags: html, meteor

Any idea why when putting the example html files included on meteor's site in to an HTML 5 template with top level tags fails?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

I see that they search for body/template tags etc and concatenate but not sure how to add the other tags then.

Comment: You should paste some of the code that you have tried.  Difficult to help debug if we don't know what you've got :)

Comment: @nzifnab I didn't really have a specific html file in general that I was debugging.  I just noticed all html outside of those tags didn't work.  Next time I will be cognizant to try to at least use some example.  That being said, there are a lot of boiler plate hmtl5 templates and I was more curious in general how to use any of these if you can't even add html outside of these tags since it is a DSL.  Hopefully I will figure out where to add eventually!

Answer (score 3):

The '.html' file you're editing as part of your Meteor application isn't an HTML file at all, but a DSL (domain specific language) that is parsed by Meteor as HTML.

As soon as you run meteor to launch a server or deploy it, it will be parsed and interpreted, and all documents will be output as HTML5 (using the ).

You can see that on any deployed meteor app, that is the first line, even though entering it in to your '.html' file in the project will cause the compiler to crash.

Answer (score 2):

I was confused by this at first as well, apparently the '.html' example files they include are intended to consist of html **fragments** rather than serving as html documents in and of themselves. According to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp):

> HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently
>   from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your
>   directory for three top-level elements: `<head>`, `<body>`, and
>   `<template>`. The head and body sections are seperately concatenated
>   into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on
>   initial page load.

As far as I can tell, any html that is included that isn't contained within any of those three tags -- including `<!doctype html>` declarations, `<html>` tags or even `<!--html comments-->` -- causes the app to crash. Hopefully that's something that they'll fix eventually.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, and for that ridiculous error message you get when you put something other <head>, <body>, or <template> at the top level in an html file. That's my fault :) This needs some work, especially the error message.

Answer (score 1):

When the server is started and you access the page it automatically adds the DOCTYPE in.